# ./executable: cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, shell-script, executable

I have a script that works well when I ssh to the server to execute it myself, but has problems when [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org), a continuous integration server, runs it.

I am automating tests on an embedded linux system (the target). The target is connected to Server A (RHEL 5) via serial and operated over minicom. Server B (FC 12) builds the tests that actually run on the target, and can ssh to Server A. Server C (RH) hosts Hudson, with Server B as a slave.

I've written a runscript (http://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript) script to do everything needed on the actual target; it boots the image, mounts a directory from Server B and executes the tests. A bash script on Server B invokes minicom with the runscript script along with some companion actions. I have a bash script on Server B which uses

```
ssh -t -t ServerA bashScript.sh
```

to get those tests run on the target. I am on Server C, I can get those tests run by ssh'ing to Server B and executing the script that ssh's to Server A which executes minicom with runscript. *Whew.*  To review:

Server A: Hudson uses its slave mechanism to ssh to Server B.

Server B: `kickOffTests.sh` has the line `ssh -t -t ServerA runTests.sh`

Server A: `runTests.sh` calls a perl script which invokes `minicom -S my.script ttyE1`

Target, after booting: Mounts a directory from Server B, where the tests are, and enters that directory. It invokes yet another bash script, which runs the tests, which are compiled C executables.

Now, when *I* execute any of these scripts myself, they do what they should. However, when Hudson tries to do the same thing, over in the minicom session it complains about a line in the "yet another bash script" that invokes the C executable, `./executable`, with `./executable: cannot execute binary file`

I still have a lot to learn about linux, but I surmise this problem is a result of Hudson not connecting with a console. I don't know exactly what Hudson does to control its slave. I tried using the line `export TERM=console` in the configuration just before running kickOffTests.sh, but the problem remains.

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and how I can fix it? I cannot remove any of the servers from this equation. It may be possible to take minicom out of the equation but that would add an unknown amount of time to this project, so I'd much prefer a solution that uses what I already have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The message `cannot execute binary file` has nothing to do with terminals (I wonder what led you to think that — and I recommend avoiding making such assumptions in a question, as they tend to drown your actual problem in a mess of red herrings). In fact, it's bash's way of expressing `ENOEXEC` (more commonly expressed as `exec format error`.

First, make sure you didn't accidentally try to run this executable as a script. If you wrote `. ./executable`, this tells bash to execute `./executable` in the same environment as the calling script (as opposed to a separate process). That can't be done if the file is not a script.

Otherwise, this message means that `./executable` is not in a format that the kernel recognizes. I don't have any definite guess as to what is happening though. If you can run the script on that same machine by invoking it in a different way, it can't just be a corrupt file or a file for the wrong architecture (it might be that, but there's more to it). I wonder if there could be a difference in the way the target boots (perhaps a race condition).

Here's a list of additional data that may help:

- Output of `file …/executable` on server B.
- Some information about the target, such as the output of `uname -a` if it's unix-like.
- Check that the target sees the same file contents each time: run `cksum ./executable` or `md5sum ./executable` or whatever method you have on the target just before yet-another-bash-script invokes `./executable`. Check that the results are the same in the Hudson invocation, in your successful manual invocation and on server B.
- Add `set -x` at the top of yet-another-bash-script (just below the `#!/bin/bash` line). This will produce a trace of everything the script does. Compare the traces and report any difference or oddity.
- Describe how the target is booting when you run the scripts manually and when Hudson is involved. It could be that the target is booted differently and some loadable module that provides the support for the format of `./executable` doesn't get loaded (or is not loaded yet) in the Hudson invocations. You might want to use `set -x` in other scripts to help you there, and inspect the boot logs from the target.

Comment: If the script contains ". ./executable" then wouldn't I encounter this problem no matter how the script is invoked? When I invoke "./kickOffTests.sh", there are several layers of scripts down before "./executable" is invoked on the target. You're right that I shouldn't make assumptions in the question, but since the only thing that's different is how the parent script is invoked, where one way is by hand in an open ssh terminal and the other is automatically by Hudson, it seems the answer lies in that difference.

Comment: @jasper77: I realize now the error message doesn't quite mean what I initially thought (though if your issue is related to terminals, the connection is very indirect). See my revised answer, and try to provide as much of the suggested additional data as you can.

Comment: I admit red faced for the benefit of others that the scripts were *not* doing exactly what I thought. Gilles nailed it; the executables had been built for a different target. In a "make -C" line of one script, I had left off a target name, so the default target was built instead of the one I intended. Once I fixed that, Hudson is successfully able to drive the minicom sesson. Since I had been running into problems relating to a console application running from ssh, and learned about 'export TERM=console' and "ssh -t -t" along the way, I was convinced my problems were there. Thanks Gilles!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you're missing the shebang line at the top of your script. Make sure the script starts with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This only showed up for me when I ran the script with `sudo -u <user>`