# "Permission denied" when starting binary despite "rwx" priviledge

Tags: bash, permissions, executable

I am trying to run the statistics software Stata 11 on Ubuntu 11.10. as a regular user and I get the following error message:

```
bash: xstata: Permission denied
```

The user priviledges seem ok to me, tough:

```
-rwxr-x--x 1 root root 16177752 2009-08-27 16:29 xstata*
```

I would very much appreciate some advice on how to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `ls` output you can see the file owner(root) and group(root). The user priviiledges apply to file owner (`rwx`), file group (`r-x`) and others (`--x`). Because you are not the root (and I suppose that you are not in the root group), only `other` (`--x`) applies to you. Thus you can run the file, but not read it. As a quick fix, try `chmod +r xstata`, this gives the read permission to all.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I followed your advice but now I get the following error message:

    "bash: .: xstata: cannot execute binary file"

- Any idea what this could mean?

Comment: this means that bash doesn't know how to run the file. Take a look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=964335

Comment: @Dominik type `file xstata` to see what the file actually is. My guess is that if it is a binary program, it was compiled for different architecture (like 64 vs 32-bit or ARM arch. or simply a newer processor than yours).

Comment: Thank you all. I figured out that I just executed the file with the wrong syntax. It works with `./xstata`. Cheers!

Comment: @Dominik what you wrote suggests that you previously run just `xstata` and the output was *"cannot execute binary file"* - right? If so, than there probably is a broken copy of the file somewhere else in your `PATH` - you should clean up. See also [this question about running programs on Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-run-my-own-program-without-specifying-its-path/).

Comment: @Dominik As rozcietrzewiacz wrote, “cannot execute binary file” likely indicates that there's a binary for the wrong architecture in your `$PATH` (wrong architecture means a 64-bit program on a 32-bit system, or a 64-bit program on a 64-bit system that doesn't have 32-bit support installed). See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3580/executable-cannot-execute-binary-file).

Comment: The command `which xstata` should help you find it.