# Remote app - bash: cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, ssh, executable

I have an app in a remote Linux machine. I am trying to execute the app via ssh, but I get the error:

```
bash: /app: cannot execute binary file
```

Why is this happening? The application works fine in the remote machine.

UDATE:

Note related to [./executable: cannot execute binary file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3580/executable-cannot-execute-binary-file#comment3916_3581) since it was a 'make' problem.

Comment: Not really, because in that case, the problem was a 'make' issue.

Comment: What is the output from `file ./executable`?  Where `./executable` is the file you're trying to run?

Comment: What is the full command you're using to launch the app?

Answer (score 0):

Check mount entry in fstab for exec permission. Check if user account on the remote server shell in etc password.

Comment: `noexec` results in "Permission denied" error.